# How to delete path via Command Prompt

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path

I want to do some work with visual studio code, but I get the warning indicated on the following screen. How do I delete the address I drew in red in the picture?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG60y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of deleting from cmd, you can search for environment variables in the taskbar's search box, open the best match and remove that path from there

Comment: I tried the way you said yes. However, in environment variables, "C:\WebDriver\bin;; There is no path named. So how do I delete it with cmd?

Comment: Did you check both, system variables and environment variables

Comment: Yes sir I checked now. But I can't see anything related to "WebDriver".

https://imgur.com/gallery/d2CvrX4

Comment: I didn't see it, you were right. Thanks :)